# Preventing already-selected items from appearing in subsequent completing-read-multiple completions

Tags: minibuffer, completing-read

The problem is probably more evident when using Vertico, but I suspect the behavior is present in `completing-read-multiple` itself.

If I've got the following form:

```
(completing-read-multiple
 "Choose your pain! "
 (seq-map (lambda (n) (format "Option %d" n))
          (number-sequence 1 3)))
```

I can use completion to enter `Option 1`. When I add a comma to start another completion (`Option 1,`), I can select `Option 1` again.

I'm not sure what use-case there is for such behavior, but assuming there is, how can I make it such that the available completion table 'shrinks' as elements are selected?

Reading the definition of `completing-read-multiple`, I feel like both `PREDICATE` and `crm--collection-fn` could be relevant, but I'm not really following the implementation.